# Про implement интерфейсов

Tags: java, классы, коллекции, интерфейс, library

обнаружено, что если

- 1) создать класс A
- 2) создать интерфейс IA
- 3) создать класс B
- 4) создать класс D
- 5) в классе A имплементировать интерфейс IA
- 6) в классе A реализовать методы имплементированного интерфейса IA
- 7) класс B наследовать от класса A
- 8) в класс B имплементировать интерфейс IA
- 9) в классе B не реализовать методы интерфейса IA (логично, так как в суперклассе данного класса уже требование реализации выполнено)

то

- 1) компилятор не ругается
- 2) в классе D можно вызвать объект класса B через ссылку интерфейса IA

Но каков может быть смысл данного факта/лайфхака, если в случае удаления имплементации интерфейса IA из класса B - все равно будет возможно вызвать объект класса B через ссылку интерфейса IA?

уточню вопрос: почему компилятор не предупреждает о лишнести имплементации интерфейса IA в класс B?

дополнительно: в случае если суперкласс является абстрактным классом, можно было пробовать понять логику данного лайфхака следующим образом:

- часть методов интерфейса можно реализовать в абстрактном классе (так как абстрактный класс не обязан реализовать все методы имплементированных интерфейсов)
- другая часть методов данного интерфейса в классе наследнике

Но по сути и тут логическая нестыковка в том, что такой подход тоже не придает смысла двойному имплементацию одного и того же интерфейса двум классам (по одной имплементации для каждого класса), один из которых наследник другого.

Укреплю свою странную находку с тем, что есть использование данного лайфхака для класса ArrayList и его суперкласса AbstractList, а общий интерфейс - интерфейс List, в смысле данный интерфейс присутствует и в AbstractList и в ArrayList.

Comment: [Why does ArrayList have “implements List”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387419/why-does-arraylist-have-implements-list)

Comment: спасибо. НО как теперь закрыть вопрос если нет способа принять ваш ответ?

Comment: 8-й пункт не обязателен, т.к. B наследует интерфейс от родителя